# move mysql database to another computer (not export)

Tags: mysql

**I'm looking for a way to move mysql database from one computer to another. But instead of exporting and then importing, is there a way that I just to the place that mysql stores the database, copy the file and then move it to another computer?**

Here's why I'm trying to this.

After updating to Yosemite, I've lost the ability to connect to mysql. I understand that this is a known issue and I've researched and followed all of the directions I can find here on how to get it working again. Although these solutions seem to work for most people, I have had absolutely no luck. I even showed the issue to my Computer Science professor and he was baffled as to why it wouldn't work after he tried to fix it. I say this to say that I've tried all the conventional paths to fixing what seems to be a simple issue but have had no success. **The advice that I've been giving is to move the database somewhere else. But since I cannot connect to mysql, I cannot utilize the export function**. I've found that my databases live in /usr/local/mysql/data. Now that I've copied the file, how can I get another computer that has mysql working to recognize this database. Please pulse advise. I've spent so many hours looking into this. I'm willing to try anything at this point

Comment: Why not get a screwdriver and take out the hard disk and put in into the other machine?

Comment: The problem is with the OS. Or perhaps within my config files. Moving the hard drive would not solve the problem

Comment: I am sorry I do not know the bit'n'bods of the scenario. If windows perhaps just swap hard disk and get the right configuration. But it is useful just to transfer the files